# RDP: Maximum number of connections used

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I've trying to find what happens when we try to connect to Windows via RDP and all the connections allowed are being used.

I'm not simply trying it, because I want an answer that is global on all versions of Windows.

Comment: There isn't a universal answer to this question.  Some versions of Windows allows more then a single remote connection the rest don't and will disconnect the already connected user.

Comment: `query session /counter|find /i "sessions"` and `query session /counter` TS CALs GUI: `lsview` TS Device CALs: `lsreport.exe /F c:\report.txt [TSLicServerName1], [TSLicServerName1], … ` TS User CALs: `cscript //Nologo PerUserCALReport.vbs /W2K3 [domainFQDN] `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`I've trying to find what happens when we try to connect to Windows via RDP and all the connections allowed are being used.` - Any new connections will be refused.

`I'm not simply trying it, because I want an answer that is global on all versions of Windows.` - Any new connections will be refused.

This question isn't about how many connections are allowed in the various versions and editions of Windows and it isn't specific to any version of Windows. If you exceed the number of `allowed` connections then any new connections will be refused.

For instance, in any desktop OS (Windows Vista, 7, 8) one remote desktop connection is allowed.

In any server OS (Windows Server 2003, 2008, 2008R2, 2012, 2012R2) where the TS or RDS role has not been installed, two remote desktop connections for administration are allowed.

In any server OS (Windows Server 2003, 2008, 2008R2, 2012, 2012R2) where the TS or RDS role is installed , the number of remote desktop connections allowed is defined by the settings of the RDP protocol on the server or may be governed by Group Policy. In all cases where you you set a limit on the allowed number of connections then all new connections will be refused when that limit is reached.

Comment: Not entirely true. If you reach the max connections used, but those open connections are not in use, you get the ability to connect to one of these sessions (given that you connect to the same user). If they are still connected to (or at least if windows thinks this is) only then, the connection is actively refused.

Comment: In that case you are not connecting to a new session, you are reconnecting to an established session (whether from the same workstation or by the same human user or not). If Jim has a session and Bob connects to Jim's session by using Jim's credentials then Bob is reconnecting to Jim's session. Bob is not establishing a new connection. You can not establish a `new` connection once the connection limit has been reached.

Comment: Likewise, if Joe disconnects and reconnects from his session or connects to his session from a different workstation he is connecting to an established session. He is not establishing a new session. Once the session/connection limit is reached all `new` connections are refused.

Comment: Yes I know, but to be thorough, I mentioned it.

Comment: My bad on reconnecting to established sessions. I just tested this and you `CAN NOT` reconnect to an established session once the connection limit is reached (whether it's disconnected or you're connecting from a different workstation). It is a hard limit. So, once the connection limit has been reached `ALL` connections will be refused.